# How do I fix error 400 on apt-get dist-upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, ansible

I'm running a large ansible playbook on a local VM for testing. I've tried it both using a VM provisioned by vagrant (using https://app.vagrantup.com/geerlingguy/boxes/ubuntu1604) and on a manually created VM using Ubuntu Server 16.04. In both situations, it often fails on running apt

```
  apt:
    upgrade: dist
    update_cache: yes
```

and

```
  apt:
    name: nginx
    state: present
    update_cache: yes
```

giving an error 400, eg:

```
    E: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/j/jbigkit/libjbig0_2.1-3.1_amd64.deb  400  Bad Request [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
```

I've done a lot of googling around the topic, and haven't come up with anything yet.

I can successfully ping the IP, but logging in and manually running `sudo apt-get install nginx` also fails:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core libfontconfig1 libgd3 libjbig0 libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8 libtiff5 libvpx3 libxpm4 nginx-common
  nginx-core
Suggested packages:
  libgd-tools fcgiwrap nginx-doc ssl-cert
The following NEW packages will be installed
  fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core libfontconfig1 libgd3 libjbig0 libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8 libtiff5 libvpx3 libxpm4 nginx
  nginx-common nginx-core
0 to upgrade, 13 to newly install, 0 to remove and 111 not to upgrade.
Need to get 2,858 kB of archives.
After this operation, 9,311 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libjpeg-turbo8 amd64 1.4.2-0ubuntu3.1 [111 kB]
Err:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libjbig0 amd64 2.1-3.1
  400  Bad Request [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
Get:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 fonts-dejavu-core all 2.35-1 [1,039 kB]
Ign:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 fontconfig-config all 2.11.94-0ubuntu1.1
Get:5 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libfontconfig1 amd64 2.11.94-0ubuntu1.1 [131 kB]
Get:6 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libjpeg8 amd64 8c-2ubuntu8 [2,194 B]
Get:7 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libtiff5 amd64 4.0.6-1ubuntu0.5 [149 kB]
Get:8 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libvpx3 amd64 1.5.0-2ubuntu1 [732 kB]
Get:9 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libxpm4 amd64 1:3.5.11-1ubuntu0.16.04.1 [33.8 kB]
Get:10 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libgd3 amd64 2.1.1-4ubuntu0.16.04.10 [126 kB]
Get:11 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 nginx-common all 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 [26.7 kB]
Get:12 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 nginx-core amd64 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 [429 kB]
Get:13 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 nginx all 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 [3,506 B]
Get:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 fontconfig-config all 2.11.94-0ubuntu1.1 [49.9 kB]
Fetched 2,831 kB in 0s (6,789 kB/s)
E: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/j/jbigkit/libjbig0_2.1-3.1_amd64.deb  400  Bad Request [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

As requested:

```
kay@ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 172.16.0.11
search company.companyname.com
```

```
kay@ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
#

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 16.04.5 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20180731)]/ xenial main restricted

#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 16.04.5 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20180731)]/ xenial main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any transient error (I believe you have a transient error here) can be solved by using `until`/`retry` combination: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#do-until-loops

Example:

```
- name: Install packages
  become: true
  apt:
    name: [packages]
    update_cache: true
    cache_valid_time='{{ apt_cache_valid_time|d(3600) }}'
  register: apt_result
  retries: '{{ apt_retries }}'
  delay: 10
  until: apt_result|success
  tags:
   - apt
   - install
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this isn't an `ansible` related question, but rather a network/firewall issue.

Questions for you to answer:

1. Can you successfully ping `91.189.88.161` from both the provider and ubuntu 16.04 vm?
2. Can you install *other* packages than Nginx
3. How often does it fail, and when it fails, for how long does it fail?
4. From which environment are you running this from? (home|work|other)?
5. Which version of Ansible are you using.
6. In short, provide a more verbose reaction and be specific :)

Seems that the resolver address set in `resolv.conf` file blocked the connection. Setting it to `8.8.8.8` fixed it.

Comment: I'm doing it from work, but my boss assures me there is no proxy in the way. Ansible 2.7.7

Comment: paste your /etc/apt/sources.list and your /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: added to question

Comment: Can you edit your resolv.conf and change `nameserver 172.16.0.11` to `nameserver 8.8.8.8` and remove the `search company.companyname.com` string.

Comment: that did it, at least for manual installs. I'm concerned it might get overwritten, though, as the file includes that warning?

Comment: Do you know if this is something that can be set when building the machine, either through vagrant or manually? as I have multiple VMs due to testing for a suite of machines, and editing it manually would be faffy

Comment: Would be handy to ask a new question for this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have internet access on the VM?? try:

wget http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/j/jbigkit/libjbig0_2.1-3.1_amd64.deb

If this is no working than you have a internet access issue.

Comment: Yes that is it.. your connection at least you cannot connect to 91.189.88.162  on port 80 ..

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear [400  Bad Request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1)

> E: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/j/jbigkit/libjbig0_2.1-3.1_amd64.deb  400  Bad Request [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

The URL is OK. Run from the command line at 91.189.88.161 80

```
# apt update
# apt install nginx
```

If this works then this might be an Ansible problem.